# Shellcode and format string vulnerabilities?

Tags: c, linux, security, shellcode

Here at my job, we have a lot of machines running RH 9, RH Enterprise 3 and some older Linux tastes. As I read about the "format string vulnerability" and "shellcode", I would like to know how to see if that Linux are vulnerable to these kinds of attack (without running the attacks itself)...

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all a shellcode is not a vulnerably.  Shellcode is a small bit of executable code that  is a payload delivered by a memory corruption vulnerability like a dangling pointer or buffer overflow.   Modern Linux systems are very difficult to exploit.

What you need to do is run a `yum upgrade` and then you should be good.  Just keep your system up to date and thats all you have to worry about.  If you want to see if a system is remotely exploitable then should run [OpenVAS](http://www.openvas.org/) against that system.  If you want to exploit a system,  and run shellcode of your choice then you can use the [Metasploit framework](http://www.metasploit.com/).

Comment: @Leonardo Rocha btw rh3 isn't a modern system,  it is likely that they are easier to exploit and if redhat is no longer supporting it,  then `yum upgrade` will fail you should upgrade these systems.  Also this is a question for serverfault,  not stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

Get a list of the installed applications on the computer and their respective versions. Then go to a [security database](http://www.exploit-db.com/) website and see if you can find any of the installed applications on their list.

Comment: And it won't always be correct. Some distros patch up old versions, so even if the version matches, it may have a patch which fixes the vulnerability.